TypeScript and template literal greediness - puzzling inconsistent behavior
I understand that infer in template literal are non-greedy, which makes sense. However, I'm noticing some strangly inconsistent behavior that seems to make it impossible to do what I'm trying to do. Basically, my goal is to have a union type of all possible prefixes to a string, capture that prefix in a string, and then return the matched prefix. See this playground link demonstrating my problem

// not unsurprising, infer is non-greedy
type First = 'First' extends `${infer Head}${string}` ? Head : never;
//   ^?

type Starts = '[[' | '<<';

// okay, so I want to trim leading characters, no problem!
type StartsWith1 = '[[Text' extends `${Starts}${infer Rest}` ? Rest : never;
//   ^?
type StartsWith2 = '<<Text' extends `${Starts}${infer Rest}` ? Rest : never;
//   ^?

// Okay let's capture the Start.... Well that's strange, now all of a sudden it's not greedily looking for the multi-character string?
type StartsWith3 = '[[Text' extends `${infer Start extends Starts}${infer Rest}` ? Start : never;
//   ^?

// well that doesn't make sense to me... why wouldn't the result here be [[?
type StartsWith4 = '[[Text' extends `${infer Start extends Starts}${string}` ? Start : never;
//   ^?

// Okay, so it works with single characters when using infer? And it works!
type ShortStarts = '[' | '<';
type StartsWith5 = '[Text' extends `${infer Start extends ShortStarts}${infer Rest}` ? Start : never;
//   ^?



(see prev comment and pls make the appropriate [edit]s)  The issue is that infer in a template literal type acts as a placeholder, as is string and if you put two placeholders next to each other the first one only captures one character, no matter what.  So to do the kind of matching you want, you need to prevent multiple placeholders from appearing next to each other, such as the version shown in this playground link. Does that fully address the question? If so I'll write an answer explaining; if not, what's missing?

Yes, thank you this is perfect! I figured there was a cheeky way to do what I want. I updated the question to include the code directly. The only reason I didn't do it at first was the twoslash typehints don't copy out of TS Playground. I'll answer my own question

"I'll answer my own question" ?? So you used my code without attribution and without letting me write the answer with an explanation? Can you explain why?  I'm going to bed now but when I wake up, I will likely write my own answer with an actual explanation and links to documentation, at which point I hope you'll delete your answer.

Because you provided it, I understood it, and the solution was simple enough. But to be honest, I missed the part where you said you'd offer a more detailed answer. If you think there's value in providing additional information for future devs who find this question, go right ahead. I'll delete my answer!

Template literal types, as implemented in microsoft/TypeScript#40336, can have placeholders: type expressions in curly braces, like the ${X} in `xyz${X}abc`. These are resolved to string literal types where possible (e.g., if X is a union of string literal types like "DEF" | "GHI" then the template literal above resolves immediately to "xyzDEFabc" | "xyzGHIabc"). Where this is not possible, such as when the placeholder contains an infer expression or a wide type like string or number (see microsoft/TypeScript#40598), the placeholder stays unresolved.
The rule for matching unresolved placeholders is described in microsoft/TypeScript#40336:

Inference proceeds by matching each placeholder to a substring in the source from left to right: A placeholder followed by a literal character span is matched by inferring zero or more characters from the source until the first occurrence of that literal character span in the source. A placeholder immediately followed by another placeholder is matched by inferring a single character from the source.

So a placeholder followed by a non-placeholder is matched "non-greedily", but a placeholder followed by another placeholder matches exactly one character and is therefore "greedy".
This explains what you're seeing.  With `${infer Start extends Starts}${infer Rest}`, that's two unresolved placeholders next to each other, and so the first one matches one character.  The extends constraint on infer, as implemented in microsoft/TypeScript#48112, doesn't change the candidates for matching. All it could possibly do is cause the match to fail.  It doesn't have any effect on the rule that Start will, if it matches anything, will match one character.  And since Starts in your example consists of multi-character strings, the match fails.

To implement what you're trying to do, therefore, you must prevent two unresolved placeholders from appearing next to each other. The way I'd approach this is to perform two matches, where each one has only one unresolved placeholder:
type StartsWith<T extends string, P extends string> =
    T extends `${P}${infer R}` ?
    T extends `${infer _P extends P}${R}` ? _P : never : never;

In the first conditional type, the prefix P is resolved, and the inferred rest infer R is unresolved, so P can match as many characters as it needs to.  That makes R the portion of the string after the prefix. But we've lost which union member of P matched. So we do a second check were now R is resolved, and the inferred start infer _P is unresolved. Again, this can now match as many characters as it needs to, because it is not followed by another unresolved placeholder. Which recovers the information about which member matched.
Let's test it out:
type Starts = '[[' | '<<';

type Z = StartsWith<"[[Text", Starts>;
//   ^? type Z = "[["

type Y = StartsWith<"<<ABC", Starts>;
//   ^? type Y = "<<"

Looks good.
Playground link to code

I appreciate the thorough answer, this will work perfectly. I think it would be awesome if typescript allowed you to override this behavior somehow without having to match the input string twice. Seems clunky

when you use infer with a constraint that is a union type containing multi character strings TypeScript seems to prioritize character by character matching rather than trying to match the complete union members
here is how we can do workaround by checking if the string starts with any of the union members :)
type StartsWith<T extends string, U extends string> = T extends `${infer P}${string}`
  ? P extends U
    ? P
    : never
  : never;


type Z = GetPrefix<'[[Text', '[[' | '<<'>; 
// "[["

